# why icon of QSystemTrayIcon not hide in my system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qsystemtrayicon

I wrote a program that create a tray. I want to hide it with below code,but it not work(tray icon is visible). how solve this problem?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
   sysTray =QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon()
   sysTray.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('1.jpg'))
   sysTray.hide()
   app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `sysTray.show()` before `sysTray.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon, qApp, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def run_something():
    print("Running something...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Creating menu
    menu = QMenu()
    checkAction = menu.addAction("Check Now")
    checkAction.triggered.connect(run_something)
    quitAction = menu.addAction("Quit")
    quitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

    # Creating icon
    icon = QIcon.fromTheme("system-help", QIcon('avatar.jpg'))   # '1.jpg'

    # Creating tray
    trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(icon, app)
    trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)

    # Showing tray
    trayIcon.show()
    trayIcon.setToolTip("unko!")
    trayIcon.showMessage("hoge", "moge")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: no, it is not answer of my question, but with your code I understand how to solve the problem. I should add `sysTray.show()` before `sysTray.hide()` .